# Comunicação entre microservices com apollo federation

Tags: javascript, microsserviços, graphql

tenho um serviço User que possui um mutation chamada validar e tenho um serviço Post que tem uma mutation cadastrar.
Estou usando ApolloGateway como Gateway.

gostaria de saber qual a forma mais adequada de fazer que o mutation cadastrar chamar a mutation validar ?

obs: Linguagem javascript.

Comment: Olá Marcelo. Você é novo aqui, então leia as regras para postar corretamente. Está faltando os códigos para te ajudarem. Sem código, dificilmente algum ajuda. Além disso, sem código sua pergunta será negativada.

Comment: A onde estão os códigos, Marcelo?